# Слайдер фото python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Хочу сделать слайдер для фото, в модуле slider.py.

Код (main.py):

```
from slider import *

faad = PhotoImage(file="knq.png")
sht = ttk.Label(f, image=faad)
m2 = ttk.Label(f, image=img2)
slider(sht, m2, 578, 0)
```

Код (slider.py):

```
def slider(file_n, widget, x, y):
    file_n = file_n
    widget = widget
    x = x
    y = y

widget.bind('<Enter>', file_n.place(x=x, y=y))
```

Проблема в том, что картинка ставится при запуске программы, а никогда я наведу на картинку. Как это исправить?

Comment: Рекомендую почитать вот это: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). На данный момент пример из вопроса не является самодостаточным и воспроизовдимым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас вызов метода `place` произойдет сразу при запуске программы, а не при событии `<Enter>` (в метод `bind` будет передан результат вызова метода `place`, а не сам метод):

```
widget.bind('<Enter>', file_n.place(x=x, y=y))
```

Чтобы это не произошло, в качестве второго параметра нужно передавать функцию (метод) без скобок (тогда это не будет вызовом) или лямбда-функцию:

```
widget.bind('<Enter>', lambda event: file_n.place(x=x, y=y))
```